# dataTables - with a fixed column, is it possible to move the scrollbar to the outside? It also creates a gap in the table that I'd like to fix

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar, datatables

This is a bit of a continuation from this question here: [dataTables - Can't get horizontal scroll & fixed column to do their job. Seems to render differently everywhere. What am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991545/datatables-cant-get-horizontal-scroll-fixed-column-to-do-their-job-seems-t/14993977#14993977)

I got the dataTable displaying the way I want it to, for the most part. But this is what it looks like.

- I had a picture of the previous look, but I somehow managed to edit it out while posting my answer below. I didn't think you could do that.
- You can still see how it looked before by going to the jsfiddle link below.

I need to know if there's a way to not only close up that gap, that the scrollbar is clearly causing, but also if there is a way to move the scrollbar to the outside of the table.

`padding-right: 140px;` did move it over, but also covered up the Action column. I then tried to apply a z-index to the action Column, but when I moved it over, it covers up the horizontal scroll at the bottom. I can't change the height obviously because then it won't line up with the rest of the table. Any thoughts?

Comment: I've got a JSFiddle here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/biggest/3hjNc/6/

For a better look at it. Again, I need to know if there's a wway to move the vert-scroll-bar all the way to the left and removing the gap that it's creating in the header. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It took a bit of doing and a number of failures before I figured it out. Ultimately, I ended up adding a padding to the container producing the scrollbar, added a z-index to the actions div, which was already `{position: absolute;}`. Then, I added some jquery that adjusted heights and widths over several things and had to tweak the styles, accordingly.

The big part of it, after the padding and z-index and positioning, was that the table that wasn't static would scroll behind the now hovering Actions Columns. So I used jquery to insert a clone of the Actions column before it (or whatever is the last column, which may or may not be Actions on other pages, for example) so it would act as a place holder and push everything to the left and the Static Actions column would now overlap the clone and everything you want to remain visible stays to the left of it. If you do this in this way, it's important that the jquery that creates the clone column, happens before the dataTable.js and/or FixedColumns.js, because it needs the table HTML to be in place so it can do it's thing properly.

Now it looks like this:

[image]

Lots of tweaking later

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to remove the scrollbar gap from a fixed column datatable.

```
 table#mainDataTable{
       margin-left: 300px !important; 
 }


 div.DTFC_ScrollWrapper div.dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody{
       padding-left: 300px;
       left: -300px; 
 }

 div.DTFC_ScrollWrapper div.DTFC_LeftWrapper div.DTFC_LeftBodyWrapper{
       z-index: 1;
 }
```

This assumes you set `iLeftWidth` to 300px in the FixedColumn initialization. The selectors also assume `bJQueryUI`: false on datatable initialization.